# Label Text save to database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

---

i want to create one label, Label name empty.

now i change label name using this code :

```
MainMenu frm = new MainMenu();


                try
                {
                    con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
                    con.Open();
                    String sql = "SELECT SSUserID from SSUserInformation where UserName like '" + txtUserName.Text + "%'";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        frm.lbluserid.Text = rdr[0].ToString();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
```

---

then i save label name to database using this code :

```
insert into UserInfo(UserID) Values(frm.lbluserid.Text);
```

---

the problem is recored save but is empty not any value stored into database

Comment: Are you getting the value when you debug ?

Comment: when i debug label text is empty

Answer (score -1):

what if you change your sql

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO UserInfo(UserID) " +
"SELECT SSUserID from SSUserInformation where UserName like '" + txtUserName.Text + "%'";
```

EDIT

```
string SQL = "INSERT INTO [UserInfo] ([UserID]) VALUES (@UserName) " + 
" SELECT [SSUserID] FROM [SSUserInformation] WHERE [UserName] LIKE @UserName + '%' "; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: when SSUserID= 1 then set label.text=1

Comment: -1 because passing values like this is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use SQL parameters instead

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static string SaveSales(string aa, string bb, string cc, string dd, string ee, string ff, string gg,string hh,string ii)
        {

            OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
            string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Sales VALUES ( '" + aa + "' , '" + bb + "','" + cc + "','" + dd + "','" + ee + "' ,'" + ff + "' ,'" + gg + "','" + hh + "','" + ii + "'  );";
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
```

Comment: This solution is open to SQL Injection.